# How do I find f3dynamics library?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook in a machine that contains a macro that works with the f3dynamics library, it is not listed in the references box. I have looked up everywhere and I cannot find the F3dynamics library.

I need to move it to another machine so the macro runs in the new machine, I have installed office 2003, 2007, 2010 in the new machine and it is not working for those versions,

is there any macro that lists all references, including this "hidden" reference?

Comment: In case you haven't seen/tried this, maybe [this link from mrexcel.com](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/169832-object-code-error.html#post1915439) might help. I'm not familiar with this library at all, so can't really help any further.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/169832-object-code-error.html#post1915439

> There is an "AboutBox" method associated with the calendar control that is part of the f3dynamic library. I called this method in code on a machine that has no problems with this issue and it read "Microsoft Office Access Calendar Control version 11.0". **The machines I don't have this problem on of course have Access on them and the ones I have this problem on don't****.
>
> In short, it's an Access library and that is why you can't find it on your machines that don't have Access. It also explains why it isn't coming up in the References listing in Excel; it isn't marked to be available in Excel since it's an Access library. Nonetheless, it is a COM-compliant object and so it still works in Excel.

...

> I did some sleuthing and found that the culprit (if you can call it that) is the **mscal.ocx** control found both in c:\windows\system32 and in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10. That is what gets installed with Access and then allows access to that mysterious "F3Dynamic" library, which I still can't get a good look into via the Object Browser.